# Reading csv using pandas. Reassigning values 1 to 40 for soil types, and 1 to 7 for forest cover types

Tags: python, csv, pandas

In the csv input file there are 56 columns below. The sample data is as shown below. Please bear with my formatting.

```
Id,Elevation,Aspect,Slope,Horizontal_Distance_To_Hydrology,Vertical_Distance_To_Hydrology,Horizontal_Distance_To_Roadways,Hillshade_9am,Hillshade_Noon,Hillshade_3pm,Horizontal_Distance_To_Fire_Points,Wilderness_Area1,Wilderness_Area2,Wilderness_Area3,Wilderness_Area4,Soil_Type1,Soil_Type2,Soil_Type3,Soil_Type4,Soil_Type5,Soil_Type6,Soil_Type7,Soil_Type8,Soil_Type9,Soil_Type10,Soil_Type11,Soil_Type12,Soil_Type13,Soil_Type14,Soil_Type15,Soil_Type16,Soil_Type17,Soil_Type18,Soil_Type19,Soil_Type20,Soil_Type21,Soil_Type22,Soil_Type23,Soil_Type24,Soil_Type25,Soil_Type26,Soil_Type27,Soil_Type28,Soil_Type29,Soil_Type30,Soil_Type31,Soil_Type32,Soil_Type33,Soil_Type34,Soil_Type35,Soil_Type36,Soil_Type37,Soil_Type38,Soil_Type39,Soil_Type40,Cover_Type
1,2596,51,3,258,0,510,221,232,148,6279,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5
2,2590,56,2,212,-6,390,220,235,151,6225,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5
3,2804,139,9,268,65,3180,234,238,135,6121,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2
4,2785,155,18,242,118,3090,238,238,122,6211,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2
5,2595,45,2,153,-1,391,220,234,150,6172,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5
6,2579,132,6,300,-15,67,230,237,140,6031,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2
7,2606,45,7,270,5,633,222,225,138,6256,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5
8,2605,49,4,234,7,573,222,230,144,6228,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5
9,2617,45,9,240,56,666,223,221,133,6244,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5
10,2612,59,10,247,11,636,228,219,124,6230,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5
```

I need to convert that data. Following are the requirements.
 - Remove multiple columns with binary values (0 or 1) and assign the new column with range of value. For Wilderness_Ares it is from 1 to 4. For Soil_Types it is from 1 to 40.

- Remove columns Wilderness_Area1 to Wilderness_Area4. Add a single column Wilderness_Area. Assign 1 to 4 based on the input row. Example - Previously the first row in the sample input above had

  - Wilderness_Area1 = 1, now it should be Wilderness_Area = 1.
  - Wilderness_Area2 = 1, now it should be Wilderness_Area = 2.
  - Wilderness_Area3 = 1, now it should be Wilderness_Area = 3.
  - Wilderness_Area4 = 1, now it should be Wilderness_Area = 4.

    2. Remove columns Soil_Type1 to Soil_Type40. Add a single column Soil_Type. Assign 1 to 40 based on the input row. Example - Previously the first row in the sample input above had
  - Soil_Type1 = 1, now it should be Soil_Type = 1.
  - Soil_Type2 = 1, now it should be Soil_Type = 2.
  - Soil_Type3 = 1, now it should be Soil_Type = 3.
  - Soil_Type4 = 1, now it should be Soil_Type = 4.

I used the following code, yet I still get the 40 soil types in my data frame. I need to remove those columns from df. How do I do all the above?

```
df = pandas.read_csv(ifname)
df['Soil'] = 0
for i in range(1,41):
    df['Soil'] = df['Soil'] + i*df['Soil_Type'+str(i)]

print(df)
```

Following is the example of what I need.

```
Id,Elevation,Aspect,Slope,Horizontal_Distance_To_Hydrology,Vertical_Distance_To_Hydrology,Horizontal_Distance_To_Roadways,Hillshade_9am,Hillshade_Noon,Hillshade_3pm,Horizontal_Distance_To_Fire_Points,Cover_Type,Soil,Wilderness_Area
1,2596,51,3,258,0,510,221,232,148,6279,5,29,1
2,2590,56,2,212,-6,390,220,235,151,6225,5,29,1
3,2804,139,9,268,65,3180,234,238,135,6121,2,12,1
4,2785,155,18,242,118,3090,238,238,122,6211,2,30,1
5,2595,45,2,153,-1,391,220,234,150,6172,5,29,1
6,2579,132,6,300,-15,67,230,237,140,6031,2,29,1
7,2606,45,7,270,5,633,222,225,138,6256,5,29,1
8,2605,49,4,234,7,573,222,230,144,6228,5,29,1
9,2617,45,9,240,56,666,223,221,133,6244,5,29,1
10,2612,59,10,247,11,636,228,219,124,6230,5,29,1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost had it, you just need to drop the columns after assigning the values:

```
In [158]:

soil_type_cols = [col for col in df if 'Soil_Type' in col]
wilderness_cols = [col for col in df if 'Wilderness_Area' in col]

for i in range(1,41):
    df['Soil'] = i*df['Soil_Type'+str(i)]

for i in range(1,5):
    df['Wilderness_Area'] = i*df['Wilderness_Area'+str(i)]

df = df.drop(soil_type_cols+wilderness_cols, axis=1)
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 10 entries, 0 to 9
Data columns (total 14 columns):
Id                                    10 non-null int64
Elevation                             10 non-null int64
Aspect                                10 non-null int64
Slope                                 10 non-null int64
Horizontal_Distance_To_Hydrology      10 non-null int64
Vertical_Distance_To_Hydrology        10 non-null int64
Horizontal_Distance_To_Roadways       10 non-null int64
Hillshade_9am                         10 non-null int64
Hillshade_Noon                        10 non-null int64
Hillshade_3pm                         10 non-null int64
Horizontal_Distance_To_Fire_Points    10 non-null int64
Cover_Type                            10 non-null int64
Soil                                  10 non-null int64
Wilderness_Area                       10 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(14)
memory usage: 1.2 KB
```

Comment: Cool. I added that to my code. I got the following output. 

`,Id,Elevation,Aspect,Slope,Horizontal_Distance_To_Hydrology,Vertical_Distance_To‌​_Hydrology,Horizontal_Distance_To_Roadways,Hillshade_9am,Hillshade_Noon,Hillshade‌​_3pm,Horizontal_Distance_To_Fire_Points,Cover_Type,Soil,Wilderness_Area 

**0**,1,2596,51,3,258,0,510,221,232,148,6279,5,29,1 

**1**,2,2590,56,2,212,-6,390,220,235,151,6225,5,29,1 

**2**,3,2804,139,9,268,65,3180,234,238,135,6121,2,12,1 `

I do not understand the first column added by pandas (bold). Could you please shed some light on it ? Is it possible to remove it.

Comment: Looks like it is a feature in Pandas. I used `df.to_csv(ofname, index=False)` and now it works.